# How to get the key value json format in an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to return a particular type of JSON format from my sp.
Below is the JSON format I want:

I am using the dataset to fetch from Query.
I have looped in the data row from the table.
I have used the KeyValuPair type to fetch the data.
But unable to get the desired format, I only get the format key value but how to get that in the metadata.

**My desired JSON output**

```
{
"Metadata": [
{
"Key": "FirstName",
"Value": "ABC"
},
{
"Key": "LastName",
"Value": "XYZ"
}
],
"Length": 25,
"Type": "application/mp3" 
}
```

**C# code to fetch the data from sp**

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

List<Class> objList = new List<Class>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyvalList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
foreach (DataRow t in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    Class obj1 = new Class();
    obj1.FirstName = Convert.ToString(t["FirstName "]);
    obj1.LastName= Convert.ToString(t["LastName"]);
    objList.Add(obj1);
    keyvalList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("FirstName ", Convert.ToString(t["FirstName"])));
    keyvalList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LastName", Convert.ToString(t["LastName"]);

}
string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyvalList);
return JSONresult;
```

**My Class Structure**

```
public class Class
{ 
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }              
    public string LastName{ get; set; }   
}
```

**JSON format which I get**

```
[{\"key":\"FirstName\", \"Value\":\"ABC\"},{\"key":\"LastName\", \"Value\":\"XYZ\"}]
```

I get the key-value JSON but it does not get inside the metadata array.

**Update**

```
var data = new 
            {
                Metadata = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(m => new Header
        {

            key= m.Field<string>("AgentId"),
            Value= m.Field<string>("LastName"),

             FirstName = m["FirstName"].ToString(),
            LastName = m["LastName"].ToString()
        }).ToList(),
                Length = "25",
                Type = "application/mp3"
            };

            string JSONreult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            return JSONreult;
```

**Output what I get**

```
{
  "Metadata": [
    [
      {
        "Key": "FirstName",
        "Value": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "Key": "LastName",
        "Value": "DEF"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Key": "FirstName",
        "Value": "GEH"
      },
      {
        "Key": "LastName",
        "Value": "IJK"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "Length": 25,
  "Type": "application/json"
}
```

**Output How I want**

```
{
    "Metadata": [
        {
            "Key": "FirstName", 
            "Value": "ABC"   
        },   
        {     
            "Key": "LastName",     
            "Value": "XYZ"    
        }
    ], 
    "Length": 25,
    "Type": "audio/mp3", 
}
```

**The Difference**

The extra [] inside MetaData while I only need one Array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class

```
public class Data    { 
        public IList<KeyPairValue<string,string>> Metadata{ get; set; }   
     }
```

fill it with your values and then serialize that to Json.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer is updated based on comments**

Your question consists of two parts:

**1.How to populate `DataTable`**

**2.How to serialize it to json (in a custom look)**

First of all, Change your class structure like below:

```
public class Metadata
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LasstName { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public IList<Metadata> Metadata { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should populate `dt` with database query results using Linq:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

var listOfData = new Data
{
    Metadata = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(m => new FullName
        {
            Key = m["FirstName"].ToString(),
            Value = m["LastName"].ToString()
        }).ToList(),
    Length = 25,
    Type = "application/mp3"
};
```

After serializing `listOfData` to json using `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listOfData);` command, the output would be like this:

```
{ 
   "Metadata":[ 
      { 
         "Key":"John",
         "Value":"Smith"
      },
      { 
         "Key":"Adele",
         "Value":"Jones"
      }
   ],
   "Length":25,
   "Type":"application/mp3"
}
```

But it differs from your desired output:

```
{ 
   "Metadata":[ 
      { 
         "Key":"FirstName",
         "Value":"John"
      },
      { 
         "Key":"LastName",
         "Value":"Smith"
      }
   ],
   "Length":25,
   "Type":"application/mp3"
}
```

If you like to change the face of your json and serialize it in custom way, you have to implement a **[Custon JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)**, because JsonSerializer cannot change your model by itself. To do so, you have to create a class and derive it from `JsonConverter` and override its methods to shape your nodes as you like:

```
class CustomMetadataConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : class
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(T);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = new JObject(
        JArray.Load(reader)
              .Children<JObject>()
              .Select(jo => new JProperty((string)jo["Key"], jo["Value"]))
              );
        T result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), result);
        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = new JArray(
        JObject.FromObject(value)
               .Properties()
               .Select(jp =>
                   new JObject(
                       new JProperty("Key", jp.Name),
                       new JProperty("Value", jp.Value)
                   )
                )
        );

        array.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

And then call `JsonObject.SerializeObject` this way instead of calling it as always:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listOfData, Formatting.Indented /* set it depend on your need */, new CustomMetadataConverter<Metadata>());
```

You can desrialize it in the same way:

```
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json, new CustomMetadataConverter<Metadata>());
```

Here is the output:

```
{
  "Metadata": [
    [
      {
        "Key": "FirstName",
        "Value": "John"
      },
      {
        "Key": "LastName",
        "Value": "Smith"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Key": "FirstName",
        "Value": "Adele"
      },
      {
        "Key": "LastName",
        "Value": "Jones"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "Length": 25,
  "Type": "application/json"
}
```

Comment: How can I loop from a dataset from this type of class structure? Moreover, I am using dataset DataAdapter to fetch from the sp. So I need one of the key-value ans other normal JSON.

Comment: outer data in array-like "Length" and "Type" are not in my database I am referring them directly from class.  So how to write them in that case.

Comment: I tried the above you suggested but I do not get the data in a key-value format the data what i get is like {Metadata:[{"FirstName":"ABC","LastName":"XYZ"] and I don't want it in that way, I want it in { MetaData: [{"Key":"FirstName", Value:"ABC"}, {"Key":"LastName", Value:"XYZ"}], "length":25, "type":"application/mp3"}

Comment: I tried the code check out in Update this code gives me key-value type but the problem is this can be done for one key value if there are multiple types how to get that

Comment: What's the output of your new query (the query you wrote in your answer)?

Comment: "{\"Metadata\":[{\"Key\":\"ABC\",\"Value\":\"XYZ\"},{\"Key\":\"ABC\",\"Value\":\"XYZ\"}]}     " I want it like "{\"Metadata\":[{\"Key\":\"FirstName\",\"Value\":\"ABC\"},{\"Key\":\"LastName\",\"Value\":\"XYZ\"}]}

Comment: @Achuthan I've updated my answer. Give it a try and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: "{\"Metadata\":[{\"Key\":\"ABC\",\"Value\":\"XYZ\"},{\"Key\":\"ABC\",\"Value\":\"XYZ\"}], lenght:"", type:""} " I want it like "{\"Metadata\":[{\"Key\":\"FirstName\",\"Value\":\"ABC\"},{\"Key\":\"LastName\",\"Value\":\"XYZ\"}], } same output I want FirstName and LastName as my Keys  and the respective value shall go in Value json

Comment: Also, @MasLoo is there a method where I can get my length and type received after each array of my metadata? like {\"Metadata\":[[{\"Key\":\"FirstName\",\"Value\":\"ABC\"},{\"Key\":\"LastName\",\"Value\":\"XYZ\"}],\"Length\":\25\,\"Type\":\"application/mp3\"}, again for other metadata vakue followe by length and type?

Comment: @Achuthan Then you don't need a `List<Metadata>`, you should change your property in `Data` to `public Metadata Metadata {get; set;}` and then change your query in a way that it assigns `Length` and `Type` to each `listOfData` items, then call serializer in the exact same way as shown in the answer, but for deserializer use `JArray` instead of `JObject`.

Comment: I didn't notice but there are a couple of array coming up,{
  "Metadata": [
    [                    which i don't want it must be only one array  "Metadata": [ {} followed by json values

Comment: The best way to learn something new is to try solving problems with it. Don't give up, you can do it.

Comment: Thanks, @MasLoo for the support, I am a newbie to this coding world and am completely in a learning phase making some projects, in this one particularly everything is done (using REST) the only Format of my input is what I am finding difficult to customize.

Comment: I tried but unable to customize in the way I want. I want to return key-value only in one array.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and show me your desired output? Add at least two entity to your output, a real combination of `Metadata`, `Lenght`, and `Type`.

Comment: I have edited the answer please check **how I get** and **how I want** the output. there is an extra array in which key-value comes up.

Comment: @Achuthan **What you want is not a json valid format.** When you need to get single pair of `FirstName` and `LastName` you have to include a simple property in your data class, **But**, when you need collection of `FirstName`s and `LastName`s and **only sometimes** you want to return single entity, you **HAVE** to have `List<Metadata>` in your `Data` class. It leads to have extra brackets, because you're returning one value from a collection. **List<Metadata> is a collection, you cannot behave it as a single entity**. Code in answer will produce you a json valid format.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make many hops like that. You could say use LinqToSQL or LinqToEF, along with Newtonsoft's Json.Net from NuGet and your code would simply be like:

```
var data = new 
{
    MetaData = db.TableName
        .Select(row => new { Key = row.FieldForKey, Value = row.FieldForValue }),
    Length = 25,
    Type = "application/mp3"
};
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

If you still want to use ADO.Net instead, you still could do it like:

```
var tbl = new DataTable();
new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, "your connection string here").Fill(tbl);

var data = new 
{
    MetaData = tbl.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(t => new { Key = t.Field<string>("KeyColumn"), Value = t.Field<string>("ValueColumn")}),
    Length = 25,
    Type = "application/mp3"
};
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

EDIT: Although I find it weird, here is a full sample using Northwind sample database:

```
var tbl = new DataTable();
new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select t.* 
    from Customers c1
    cross apply (select 'FirstName', customerId from customers c2 where c1.CustomerId = c2.CustomerId
               union
               select 'LastName', CompanyName from customers c2 where c1.CustomerId = c2.CustomerId) t([Key], [Value])
               ",@"server=.\SQLExpress2012;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=yes").Fill(tbl);

var data = new 
{
    MetaData = tbl.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(t =>  new { 
            Key = t.Field<string>("Key"), 
            Value = t.Field<string>("Value") } ),
    Length = 25,
    Type = "application/mp3"
};
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```